# Typescript type guards array find requires filtering before find

Tags: typescript, typeerror, typeguards

I have created a type guard to check if an object is of a specific type. If I try to use array find with the type guard and a second condition I get a type error but if I use array find with the type guard on it's own followed by find I don't receive an error.

Type guard:

```
const isHtmlField = (
    field: GravityForms.Field
): field is GravityForms.HtmlField => {
    return field.type === 'html'
}
```

The following gives me a type error:

```
const description: GravityForms.HtmlField | undefined = fields.find(
    (item) => {
        isHtmlField(item) && item.label.toLowerCase() === "description";
    }
);
```

Whereas this one works

```
const description: GravityForms.HtmlField | undefined = fields
    .filter(isHtmlField)
    .find((item) => item.label.toLowerCase() === "description");
```

In my types.d.ts I have the following:

```
declare namespace GravityForms {
    export interface Field {
        type: string;
        id: string;
        pageNumber: number;
        cssClass: string;
        label: string;
    }

    export interface RadioField extends Field {
        type: "radio";
        choices: {
            text: string;
            value: string;
            isSelected: boolean;
        }[];
    }

    export interface HtmlField extends Field {
        type: "html";
        content: string;
    }

    export type FormFields = (Field | RadioField | HtmlField)[];

    export interface Form {
        fields: FormFields;
        pagination: {
            pages: string[];
        };
    }
}

interface FormPage {
    title: string;
    fields: GravityForms.Form["fields"];
}

type FormPages = FormPage[];

type UpdateDataItem = (id: string, value: string) => void;

interface FormSubmissionData {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

The complete page component where I'm trying to use the description:

```
const Page: FC<IPage> = ({ title, fields, hidden, incrementPage }) => {
    const description: GravityForms.HtmlField | undefined = fields
        .filter(isHtmlField)
        .find((item) => item.label.toLowerCase() === "description");

    console.log(`fields`, fields);

    return (
        <div
            className={classNames({
                hidden,
            })}
        >
            <div className="mb-3 md:mb-12">
                <h2 className="text-3xl leading-loose">{title}</h2>

                {description && (
                    <p className="text-white text-2xl font-bold">
                        {description.content}
                    </p>
                )}
            </div>

            {fields.map((field) => (
                <>
                    {isRadio(field) &&
                        field.cssClass.includes("convert-to-icons") && (
                            <IconRadio {...field} onClick={incrementPage} />
                        )}

                    {isTextField(field) && (
                        <>
                            <label htmlFor={field.id}>{field.label}</label>
                            <input type="text" id={field.id} name={field.id} />
                        </>
                    )}
                </>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: what is the type of `fields ` ? Could you please add your fields declaration as well?

Comment: The form data comes from an api but I've added the component where I'm trying to use the code, the type of fields is `GravityForms.Form["fields"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. First:

```ts
const description: GravityForms.HtmlField | undefined = fields.find(
    (item) => {
        isHtmlField(item) && item.label.toLowerCase() === "description";
    }
);
```

Callback function here is not a predicate (function returning `boolean`). Your function always returns `undefined`. You should replace curly brackets with round brackets and remove semicolon for it to work properly:

```ts
const description: GravityForms.HtmlField | undefined = fields.find(
    (item) => (
        isHtmlField(item) && item.label.toLowerCase() === "description"
    )
);
```

Another problem is while your callback function uses type predicate *inside* it's body it **doesn't** convey to typescript the result type of the callback function itself. You should make *namely* the callback function itself a type guard:

```ts
const descriptionBad: GravityForms.HtmlField | undefined = fields.find(
    (item): item is GravityForms.HtmlField => (
        isHtmlField(item) && item.label.toLowerCase() === "description"
    )
);
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wRJpvw)

And that's the exact reason why your second function with `filter` works as expected. You're using *the type guard* as the callback function there.

Comment: Thanks! Something that confuses me about typescript is why can't you infer the type of `description` without adding the type guard to the callback of `find`? If `find` returns a value, then `isHtmlField` must have returned true.

Comment: Callback function in the `find` returns just a boolean. It doesn't bring any type information unless you exactly tell the typescript so.